# How to use sed to comment and add lines in a config-file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am looking for a way to achieve the following:

A certain directory contains 4 (config) files:

- File1
- File2
- File3
- File4

I want my bash script to read in each of the files, one by one. In each file, look for a certain line starting with "params: ". I want to comment out this line and then in the next line put "params: changed according to my will".

I know there are a lot of handy tools such as sed to aid with these kind of tasks. So I gave it a try:

```
sed -ri 's/params:/^\\\\*' File1.conf
sed -ri '/params:/params: changed according to my will' File1.conf
```

Questions: Does the first line really substitute the regex `params:` with `\\` following a copy of the entire line in which `params:` was found? I am not sure I can use the * here.

Well, and how would I achieve that these commands are executed for all of the 4 files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this command will comment every line beggining by `params:` in you files, and append a text in the next line

```sh
sed -E -i 's/^(params:.*)$/\/\/\1\nYOUR NEW LINE HERE/g'
```

the pattern `^(params:.*)$` will match any whole line beggining by params:, and the parenthesis indicate that this is a capturing group.

Then, it is used in the second part of the sed command via `\1`, which is the reference of the first capturing group found. So you can see the second part comments the first line, add a line break and finally your text.

You can execute this for all your files simply by going `sed -E -i 's/^(params:.*)$/\/\/\1\nYOUR NEW LINE HERE/g' file1 file2 file3 file4`

Hope this helps!

Comment: awesome, thx so much! ... one last thing: why are u using -E instead of -r? I thought -r is used to allow regexs. And -e is used to execute a script. ... which I guess we are, because of 's ? Does -E need to be capital?

Comment: -r and -E are actually the same option, but with different names. From `man sed` : `-E, -r, --regexp-extended: use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).`

Comment: ah okay, I see. Btw, does `^(params:.*)$` neglect spaces that come before params? Since my line is actually indented

Comment: No it won't work since ^ indicate the beggining of a line, you'd need to add the number of spaces you have in you file after, for instance `^    (params:.*)$`. Or if you want to neglect any number of spaces : `^[[:space]]*(params:.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for i in **conf
do
    cp $i $i.bak
    sed -i 's/\(params:\)\(.*\)$/#\1\2\n\1new value/' 
done
```

With: `\(params:\)\(.*\)`

- match `params:` and store it in `\1
- match text following `.*\:` and store it in `\2`

Then create two lines:

- The initial line commented: `#\1\2\n`
- The new line with your wanted value: `\1new value`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel --dry-run -q sed -i 's/^params:/#&/;T;aparams: bla bla' {} ::: file[1-4]
```

Run this in the desired directory and if the commands are correct remove the `--dry-run` option and run for real.